# Does a div need to be displayed to be used as a waypoint?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm using JQuery waypoints to try and trigger events with the scroll of the mouse. But the page itself isn't scrolling. I'm using "waypoint" divs as triggers since the divs with content in them are not supposed to be scrolling. But the waypoint divs aren't registering currently. So the question is,since the divs themselves don't have scrollbars and I'm just listening for the scroll event, do I need to be showing the waypoint divs with display:block even if they have no content?

Perhaps a look at the markup will be more helpful to understand the problem. Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <p class="homeLink">Words N' Pics</p>
            <div id="menuButton"><img class="menuIcon" src="images/menuIcon.png"/></div>
        </header>
        <div id="waypointOne"></div>
        <div id="waypointTwo"></div>
        <div id="waypointThree"></div>
        <div id="waypointFour"></div>
        <div id="slideOne" class="slider">
            <div class="sliderPic"><img src="images/Sgt-Bilko.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="sliderText"><p>This is come content just chilling right here.</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slideTwo" class="slider">
            <div class="sliderPic"><img src="images/Sgt-Bilko.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="sliderText"><p>This is come content just chilling right here.</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slideThree" class="slider">
            <div class="sliderPic"><img src="images/Sgt-Bilko.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="sliderText"><p>This is come content just chilling right here.</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slideFour" class="slider">
            <div class="sliderPic"><img src="images/ralph.jpg"/></div>
            <div class="sliderText"><p>This is come content just chilling right here.</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="arrowJumper"><img class="arrowIcon" src="images/greyArrow.png"/></div>
    </footer>
    <div id="menuOverlay" class="menuDiv">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Work.</li>
            <li>About.</li>
            <li>Careers.</li>
            <li>Ideas.</li>
            <li>News.</li>
            <li>Events.</li>
            <li>Contact.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here's the relevant bits of my CSS (please take note, this is only a segment. The rest will be in a fiddle at the end):

```
#waypointOne{
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
}

#waypointTwo{
    position:absolute;
    top:250px;
}

#waypointThree{
    position:absolute;
    top:350px;
}

#waypointFour{
    position:absolute;
    top:450px;
}
```

And the Jquery:

```
$(function () { // When the page has loaded,
    $('#waypointOne').waypoint(function () {
        alert("Waypoint 1 reached.");
    })
});

$(function () { // When the page has loaded,
    $('#waypointTwo').waypoint(function () {
        alert("Waypoint 2 reached.");
    })
});

$(function () { // When the page has loaded,
    $('#waypointThree').waypoint(function () {
        alert("Waypoint 3 reached.");
    })
});
```

The specific question is, "Why are the waypoints not getting picked up?" But the broader question is, do divs like this need to be shown on the screen to be targeted by Waypoints (i.e. display:block)? or can they be hidden and simply be used in the background? Here's a fiddle. Note that currently, a click will do what the scroll should be doing. But the scroll should be alerting and it's not.

http://jsfiddle.net/rcJP9/

For some reason the click isn't working in the fiddle. But the full-page divs are supposed slide up to reveal what is behind them.

Comment: in your fiddle, the scripts aren't loading because they are relative to the project you copy and pasted from. You can probably add it to the resources panel on the left from a cdn -- but really you can probably get to the bottom of this with a more simplified test.  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5tC2p/

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5tC2p/), I'm going to say that the id anchor points don't register when display none.

How about something like this? Should be virtually invisible, but still hold it's place in the dom...

```
.visually-hidden { /*http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2012/10/clip-your-hidden-content-for-better-accessibility/*/
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    padding:0 !important;
    border:0 !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
} 
body:hover .visually-hidden a, body:hover .visually-hidden input, body:hover .visually-hidden button { display: none !important; }
```

Here is [another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/5tC2p/2/) with that in place. Seems to be working!

Comment: Boss! Thanks! I'll try this now! Nice fiddle by the way. It's always a big help for me to see it in action.

Comment: One question. Will this be triggered even if the page doesn't use scrollbars? Because the divs are not exactly scrolling. They're sitting there. And they are supposed to slide away when I use scroll on the mouse.

Comment: Not really sure. I primarily design mobil first - and way-points etc are a nightmare for responsive design and touch devices, ... my fiddle was just based on the theory that they are hooking into the #id's in a similar way of native anchor links. My answer may not be correct. : )  I hope it is though, for your sake!

Comment: I appreciate the help either way. I'll give it a shot! Many thanks!